# Porque se borra el archivo .dat al terminar el programa

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo un método que me guarda datos en un archivo, el método es el siguiente:

```
 public String escribirArchivo() throws IOException {

        String result = "ok";
        try (FileWriter entrada = new FileWriter(this.nombreArchivo)) {

            try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(entrada)) {

                //si hay atletas que guardar..
                if (Globales.atletas.length > 0) {

                    //reviso que no este lleno
                   
                    //si no esta lleno hago el ingreso
                    if (comprobarEspacio(0) != 99) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Globales.arreglosTamanio; i++) {
                            if (Globales.atletas[i] != null) {

                                pw.write(Globales.atletas[i].getnIdentificacion() + ";"
                                        + Globales.atletas[i].getNombre() + ";"
                                        + Globales.atletas[i].getApellido1() + ";"
                                        + Globales.atletas[i].getSexo() + ";"
                                        + Globales.atletas[i].getnIDAtleta() + ";"
                                        + Globales.atletas[i].getEdad() + ";"
                                        + Globales.atletas[i].getNivel() + ";"
                                        + Globales.atletas[i].getFechaNacimiento() + ";-");
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        result="atleta lleno";
                    }
                }

                if (Globales.vueltas.length > 0) {
                   

                    if (comprobarEspacio(1)!=99) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Globales.arreglosTamanio; i++) {
                            if (Globales.vueltas[i] != null) {

                                pw.write("@::" + Globales.vueltas[i].getnIDAtleta() + ";"
                                        + Globales.vueltas[i].getFechaDePractica() + ";"
                                        + Globales.vueltas[i].getNumeroDeVuelta() + ";"
                                        + Globales.vueltas[i].getTiempoObtenidoEnMinutos() + ";"
                                        + Globales.vueltas[i].getTiempoObtenidoEnSegundos() + ";");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          
        }
        
        return result;

    }
```

Como ven estoy usando AutoClosable con lo cual no necesito llamar el método close(), o bueno al menos eso es lo que creo.
El problema es que mientras el programa esta en ejecución me guarda bien los datos en el archivo pero una vez que detengo el programa todos los datos del archivo se borran!!!. Porque pasa esto?

Comment: Hola Richard por que dices que estas usando AutoClosable?, en realidad deberìas usar al final close()

Comment: Se supone que para eso es el Autoclosable???  Es como el using(){} en C# ?? O bueno al menos eso pense, voy a intentar poniendole el close()

Comment: Ah entiendo lo que dices, pero en realidad es una interfaz, revisa la documentaciòn https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html , agrega close() y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Bueno parece que el problema es otro porque ni con el flush() y el close() me funciona. Y creo que eso del AutoClosable si es como el using, este método funciona sin el close() :   public  void escribirArchivoVuelta(ArrayList<Atleta> atletas) throws IOException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(this.nombreArchivo))) {
            
            salida.writeObject(atletas);
        }
    }

Comment: @Jorgesys Si efectivamente el AutoClosable hace lo mismo que el using en C# , lo puede comprobar con ese método que le comente. Sin embargo no entiendo porque con ObjectOutputStream si funciona y con Filewriter y PrintWriter no.

Answer (score 1):

Despuès de escribir la informaciòn deberìas usar el mètodo [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close()) para cerrar el stream, esto es importante.

```
pw.write(......);
...
...
...
pw.close();
```